# ffmpeg infinite streaming of audio and video using rtmp

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to make a Youtube radio consisted of infinitely looped video.mp4 (10 seconds length) and infinitely looped audio.flac (4 hours length) streaming from my VPS. These Audio and Video streams don't require synchronization.

I tried to use FFMPEG and it worked well until I tried to make the streams looping

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i video.txt \
-f concat -i audio.txt \
-c:a aac \
-s 1920x1080 \
-ab 256k \
-b:v 2500k \
-q:v 3 \
-preset veryfast \
-vcodec libx264 \
-pix_fmt yuv240p \
-maxrate 1024k \
-bufsize 048k \
-framerate 4 \
-threads 2 \
-f flv \
"$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

(audio.txt contains 10000 identical lines of 'file audio.flac', video.txt 'file video.mp4' respectively)
'concat' filter leaves some terrible glitch resulting in my stream (both audio and video) frequently scrolled forward for 10 seconds or so.
I also tried '-stream_loop' flag but it does not work with multiple input streams.

Comment: Try ffmpeg 4.1 or newer. -stream_loop works with multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some sort of playlist to tell the stream what to play. You can use liquidsoap to do this:

Here is an example of ffmpeg and liquidsoap:

```
set("frame.video.width", 1280)
set("frame.video.height", 720)
set("frame.video.samplerate", 25)
set("gstreamer.add_borders", false)

s = playlist.safe("playlist.pls",reload_mode="watch") 

s = fallback([s, blank()])


  output.gstreamer.audio_video(
  video_pipeline=
    "videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=2000 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline ! queue ! mux.",
  audio_pipeline=
    "audioconvert ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue ! mux.",
  pipeline=
    "flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location=\"rtmp://[YOUR_IP]:1935/example/live live=1\"",
  s)
```

Here are the full steps you need to take:

https://github.com/fyroc/RTMP-Playlist

In your case, just add the single file to the playlist file and it will loop over it.